# How to delete dynamic property of an object?

Tags: javascript, object

I try to delete an dynamic property of an object. The problem is that the property is depending of an array of keys. Lets see the code :

```
let keys = ['23', 'test', '12']; // Example but this is dynamic
let temp = this.array;
keys.forEach(k => {
  temp = temp[k];
});
delete temp;
```

I want to delete this.array['23']['test']['12']. But I got an error : 'delete cannot be called on an identifier in strict mode'. How to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to delete this.array['23']['test']['12']

Writing just that, `delete this.array['23']['test']['12']`, will work. But with your syntax, `delete temp`, you aren't deleting a property, you're trying to delete a variable. That won't fly. Even in the non-strict mode it won't alter the `this.array` object, you'd be simply declaring a variable and undeclaring it.

With your loop, you should stop one step earlier to delete a property, not a variable:

```
keys.forEach((key, index, arr) => {
  if (index < arr.length - 1) { 
    temp = temp[key];
  } else {
    delete temp[key];
  }
});
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to delete it but you can set it to `null`.  Try:

```
temp = null;
```